# generate labels with pattern in reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I have 20 speakers.

I want to create 20 labels and put one on every speaker, but with this pattern as they go per pair:

```
speaker1, speaker2 = label 1
speaker3, speaker4 = label 2
speaker5, speaker6 = label 3
speaker7, speaker8 = label 4
speaker9, speaker10 = label 5
and so on...
```

I am using reportlab canvas to generate the pdfs

```
def set_labels(canvas):
    for speaker in range(20):
        canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 50, leading=None)
        canvas.drawCentredString(80, 10, 'Label {}'.format(speaker)
        canvas.showPage()
        canvas.save()
```

with this, I am getting an incrementing 'Label 0' 'Label 1'... but my attempt is the pages 1 and 2 with 'Label 1' and page 3 and 4 with 'Label 2' and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can increment by a desired number with range by adding a third argument - [range(start,end,step)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

Here is the code:

```
def set_labels(canvas):

    for i in range(1,21,2):
        print("speaker", i, " speaker",i+1, "\n")
        #Do PDF operations

canvas = "placeholder"
set_labels(canvas)
```

Here is the output:
[image]

In your application, you will be operating on speaker and speaker+1 (I switched the variable name for speaker out with i for more clarity).